# exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage__Block_Catalog'

Tags: blocks, exception

I'm getting the following errors in my exception.log:

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type:
>   Mage__Block_Catalog' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php:594 Stack
>   trace:
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495):
>   Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('/catalog/produc...', Array)
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('/catalog/produc...',
>   'product_list')
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('/catalog/produc...', 'product_list')
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element),
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(146):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419):
>   Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/ArtsOnIT/OfflineMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(46):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):
>   ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   /var/www/vhosts/my.websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/index.php(137):
>   Mage::run('uk', 'website')

So it looks like the module name isn't being declared, hence the double underscore: Invalid block type: `Mage__Block_Catalog`

So my question is, *where can I find to add in the module name for this?*

Comment: Search for `type="/catalog"` in files `app/design/frontend/**/*.xml`

Answer (score 1):

`Invalid Block Type` Exception is arised by `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::_getBlockInstance()` which will be called by the method `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::createBlock()`. This is how `_getBlockInstance` look like

```
protected function _getBlockInstance($block, array $attributes=array())
{
    if (is_string($block)) {
        if (strpos($block, '/')!==false) {
            if (!$block = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($block)) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
            }
        }
        if (class_exists($block, false) || mageFindClassFile($block)) {
            $block = new $block($attributes);
        }
    }
    if (!$block instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
    }
    return $block;
}
```

Now we can go through  the method by using the invalid block type in this case. Here the invalid block type is `Mage__Block_Catalog`. So there are two possibility here.

### 1. Somewhere in your application, you are passing a block type value `Mage__Block_Catalog` to the `createBlock()` method.

if that is the case, then this is the part which generates the exception

```
    if (!$block instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type: %s', $block));
    }
```

This is because `Mage__Block_Catalog` is not a valid block class and really does not exist.

The probability for the occurance of this chance is too less.

### 2. Somewhere in your application, you are trying to create a block which is passed in this format `/catalog`.

In thi case, `$block = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($block)` will look like `$block = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('/catalog')` and hence the method return a value `Mage__Block_Catalog` and hence

```
 $block =  Mage__Block_Catalog
```

Since such a block is invalid as I stated in the first case, the method will arise an exception

My assumption is that, this is what that makes problem in your case. Somewhere in your application you have edited the core code (may be in layout xml file) and thus `block type` become `/catalog` instead of `catalog/catalog` (This will return a class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Catalog`). You need to find it and resolce it.